# Variance of the mean of a random variable with a normal distribution

Tags: distributions

I am trying to understand the methods of a medical-statistics paper I am reading. This is a direct excerpt:

> The model considered is a 2-group clinical trial (treatment v
>   control), with true (unknown) treatment effect denoted by $\mu$. The
>   outcome is continuous and normally distributed with variance assumed
>   known and equal to 0.5 (this is for convenience, so that the variance
>   of an estimate of treatment effect based on a pair of observations
>   equals 1).
>
> The trial will have 100 observations in each group, considered as 100
>   pairs of differences (random variables $X_i$  with realisations $x_i$  :
>   $i=1\dots100$). Each $X_i$  is distributed $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, and their mean $\bar{X}$ -
>   distributed $\mathcal{N}(\mu,0.01)$ with realisation $\bar{x}$ - will be used to estimate the
>   treatment effect.

I have a few questions:

1. Is "the outcome" (second sentence) referring to the outcome of each arm of the clinical trial or to a single treatment effect (i.e. difference between the two arms)?
2. Why does the variance of two outcomes with a variance of 0.5 equal 1 when estimating the treatment effect based on a pair of observations?
3. Each $X_i$ is distributed $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, so why is $\bar{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,0.01)$?

Also, if you can think of a more appropriate title for this question so it might be indexed and better searched in the future, please suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is "the outcome" (second sentence) referring to the outcome of each arm of the clinical trial or to a single treatment effect (i.e. difference between the two arms)?

Hm, hard to tell. My guess, based on the second paragraph, it's probably the difference for a pair, between the treatment vs non-treatment

> Why does the variance of two outcomes with a variance of 0.5 equal 1 when estimating the treatment effect based on a pair of observations?

It assumes that the observations are independent. I.e., the variance of a sum equal the sum of the variances.

> Each $X_i$ is distributed $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, so why is $\bar{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,0.01)$?

Remember variance is defined as

\begin{aligned}\operatorname {Var} (X)=\operatorname {E} \left[(X-\operatorname {E} [X])^{2}\right]\\ =\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}\right]-\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\end{aligned}

Here, you are comparing the variance of the random variable vs the variance of the sample mean. The variance of your sample is (where $\sigma^2$ is the variance:

$$n\left({\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{n^{2}}}\right)={\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{n}}$$

(precisely, this is for the population variance and mean, but the article probably simplifies the concept of sample mean)

Comment: Thanks! This is great! Where is the left hand side of that sample variance derived from?

Comment: That would be $$
\operatorname{Var}(\overline{X})=\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{Var}\left(X_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}} n \sigma^{2}=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}
$$

Note that it relies on the second point that the sum the variance of a sum equal the sum of the variances (which in turn assumes that the variances are uncorrelated)